# chown, chmod & bad settings on /home/user/.ssh directory in fresh install of CentOS 6

Tags: centos, ssh, chmod, chown

I just finished installing CentOS 6 last night (netinstall from georgia tech repository), and have been running into some weird SSH issues when I try to SSH from the CentOS box (behind my home network) to one of my public-facing web servers.

After running ssh-keygen on the new box (lets call it Server A), and copying the public key over to Server B, I try to SSH from A into B. I ran into some permissions issues, so made a couple of chmod's (tried changing id_rsa.pub to 0600 from 644, and then later chmod'd the .ssh dir to 0600).

As background information, I was able to successfully ssh (with rsync -e "ssh -i...") last night from Server A into Server B. No changes were made between 7 hours ago then and when I began to have problems this morning.

Here's the current scenario:

The username on Server A is dwhite. When I do an ls -la of the .ssh directory as root, I see:
drw-------. 2 dwhite dwhite 4096 Nov  5 05:38 .ssh

But when I try to do an ls -la as dwhite, I get a permission denied. So I sudoed into root and did a chmod of the .ssh directory back to 644. I get back into dwhite's account, and run ls -la:

```
[dwhite@local ~]$ ls -la .ssh/
ls: cannot access /home/dwhite/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/dwhite/.ssh/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/dwhite/.ssh/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/dwhite/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/dwhite/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa.pub
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? known_hosts
```

So I sudo'd back into root and ran:
chown -R dwhite.dwhite /home/dwhite/.ssh/

Back in as dwhite, ran ls -la:
Same exact thing

What in the world is going on? What am I missing? As this is a fresh install, I have to believe that this is user error, but I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: Looks like a corrupt filesystem to me - run fsck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and then later chmod'd the .ssh dir to 0600
>
> When I do an ls -la of the .ssh directory as root, I see:
>
> ```
> drw-------. 2 dwhite dwhite 4096 Nov 5 05:38 .ssh
> ```

The `~/.ssh` directory should has 700 permission. You see the question mask in the `ls` output due to the lack of the execute permisison. So, try this:

```
# chmod u+x /home/dwhite/.ssh
```